# SharePoint 2016 List - Edit Form - Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, 2016, sharepoint-list, edit-form

I have a SharePoint List to collect some information.  I have two radio buttons and based on which radio button is selected, only specific fields will be shown and the others hidden.

This works great on the New form, but I can't figure out how to get the Edit form to display correctly.  I need it to check on page load which radio button is already selected and only display the corresponding fields to that option.  Hopefully I've made that clear, new at this and really need some help.

Here's the code I've used on the New form, but it doesn't work properly on the Edit form:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("nobr:contains('Date Began Post Imaging Activities')").closest('tr').hide();
        $("nobr:contains('Number Post Imaging Activities to Date')").closest('tr').hide();
        $("span[title='Local Imaging']>input").change(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $("nobr:contains('Date Began Imaging')").closest('tr').show();
                $("nobr:contains('Number Imaged to Date')").closest('tr').show();
            $("nobr:contains('Date Began Post Imaging Activities')").closest('tr').hide();
                $("nobr:contains('Number Post Imaging Activities to Date')").closest('tr').hide();
            }    
        });
        $("span[title='Depot Imaging']>input").change(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $("nobr:contains('Date Began Post Imaging Activities')").closest('tr').show();
                $("nobr:contains('Number Post Imaging Activities to Date')").closest('tr').show();
            $("nobr:contains('Date Began Imaging')").closest('tr').hide();
                $("nobr:contains('Number Imaged to Date')").closest('tr').hide();
            } 
        });
});
</script>
```